# Drawing a bode plot of transfer function with unknown gain

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

I want to draw bode plot of this transfer function:

$$G(p) = {K \over p \space (1+0.1p) \space (1+0.05p)}$$

But I don't know what to do with that K (static gain) -- I've only drawn TF with known gain.

Comment: Just make your y axis G/K in dB

Comment: Thats sound good, but if i want to measure wc0 from the graph what to do ? because it will be changing with K.

Comment: No, it won't change with K

Comment: Assume K is 1. Then include the change in gain as a linear vertical shift in the final bode plot. For this (homework?) question, the K is relatively inconsequential versus working with the second-order system.

Comment: pulse at 0dB, it did change, i choosed k=1 and it was about wc0 = 1, and for K=10 it becomes wc0 = 10

Comment: Do what Scott suggests, but then express wc0 as wc0 = xK, so it's clear that it will be proportional to K.

Comment: Ah, with better formatting, it's now quite evidentially a third-order system.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's do some math to explain more explicitly what has been said in some comments to your question.

Let's rewrite G as another TF multiplied by K:

$$
G(p) = K \cdot G_n(p)
$$

where

$$
G_n(p) = \dfrac{1} {p \cdot (1+0.1p) \cdot (1+0.05p)}
$$

is the normalized (with respect to K) TF.

Let's define the logarithmic (dB) amplitude response of the system this way:

$$
A_{(dB)}(\omega) = 20 \log_{10} \left| G(j\omega) \right|
$$

We see easily that:

$$
A_{(dB)}(\omega) =
\\[1em]
= 20 \log_{10} \left| K \cdot G_n(j\omega) \right| =
\\[1em]
= 20 \log_{10} \left| K \right| 
+ 20 \log_{10} \left| G_n(j\omega) \right| =
\\[1em]
= K_{(dB)} + A_{n(dB)}(\omega)
$$

Where \$A_{n(dB)}\$ is the amplitude response relative to the normalized TF and
\$K_{(dB)}\$ is the constant K expressed in dB:

\begin{align*}
A_{n(dB)}(\omega) &= 20 \log_{10} \left| G_n(j\omega) \right|
\\[1em]
K_{(dB)} &=  20 \log_{10} \left| K \right| 
\end{align*}

From that you can see that the only difference in the amplitude Bode plot between the original and the normalized TF is just a vertical shift, so the corner frequencies of both plots will remain the same.

Here is an LTspice simulation that shows practically the situation:

[image]

[image]

Of course I had to choose a value for K (100 = 40dB), but you can easily see that any change to K will just change the amount of the vertical shift.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the function is exactly the same for all values of K (assuming you're drawing a Bode plot). Different values of K just mean a translation of the graph upwards for higher values or downwars for lower values.